# Exporting shape layers to SVG without buying Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I have Photoshop CS6, but I don't have Illustrator. Can I export shape layers to SVG, perhaps using a plugin?

Comment: I think 30 day free trial will be easiest way :)

Comment: I'd like to keep using that functionality for longer than 30 days though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) with [PSD Import Extension](http://pernsteiner.org/inkscape/psd_import/).

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
It's what I normally use.

http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg